# Why has my syntax coloring changed?

Tags: front-end, syntax-highlighting

Local variables in `Module` are no longer specially colored for me, but other syntax coloring remains, for example iterators in a `Table`:

[image]

What causes this? How can I restore the original syntax coloring behavior?

The altered behavior has persisted across hundreds of rebootings and new notebooks.

And the preference for "local variables of Module and With" is correctly set, but shows the incorrect behavior in the example:

[image]

Resetting to defaults does not restore order. Changing the color to something different also has no effect.

Restarting after clearing the `init.m` file using:

```
RenameFile["~/Library/Mathematica/FrontEnd/init.m", "~/Library/Mathematica/FrontEnd/init.m_Backup"]
```

also does not change the behavior.

Comment: 1. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p85xwZ_OLX0  2. If that doesn't work, have you checked Preferences -> Appearance -> Syntax Coloring -> Local variables?  Try the Reset to Defaults button on that page.

Comment: @Szabolcs, yes, and I'm absolutely sure it's plugged in. See edits.

Comment: Remove (backup) your front-end's init.m file and see if it works (it should).

Comment: Before you remove the init.m file, you can try this simpler thing: hold down Command+Shift while starting up Mathematica and see if it fixes it.  If it doesn't, then try what @rm said.

Comment: Clearing the user-level init.m in ~/Library/Mathematica/FrontEnd/ doesn't work. Is there another system-wide one I should try clearing out? Starting with Command+Shift also doesn't work.

Comment: @ArgentoSapiens The last resort I'd try would be clearing all of ~/Library/Mathematica, but do make sure to back it up!  It's convenient to also salvage the license file (`mathpass`) and place it back to where it belongs.  I don't think there's a *writable* system-wide setting file.